# Plots based on models with clustered SEs

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I'm trying to create a plot based on regression models with clustered standard errors. Depending on the size of the dataset, I usually cluster standard errors using `felm` from the `"lfe"` package or `cluster.vcov` and `coeftest` from the `"multiwayvcov"` and `"lmtest"` packages.

Here's an example of what the regressions might look like with those two methods:

```
# Load Packages
library('lfe')
library('multiwayvcov')
library('lmtest')
data(mtcars)

# Using felm
m1 <- felm(mpg ~ wt + disp + wt*disp | 0 | 0 | carb, data=mtcars)

# multiwayvcov
m2 <- glm(mpg ~ wt + disp + wt*disp, data=mtcars)
er2 <- cluster.vcov(m2, mtcars, 'carb')
m2ct <- coeftest(m2, er2)
```

The problem is that both of these options produce object types that are incompatible with most plotting functions in R.

For example, if I'm trying to create a plot like this:

```
interplot(m=m2, var1='wt', var2='disp', ci=.9, ralpha=.3, rfill='dodgerblue1') +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=3)))
```

How do I create plots with the correct confidence intervals from these models with clustered standard errors?

Answer (score 1):

There's a `glm.cluster` function in the `miceadds` package that fits GLMs with cluster*robust* standard errors and seems to resemble the `felm`results.

```
library(miceadds)
m.glm.cl <- glm.cluster(mpg ~ wt + disp + wt*disp, cluster="carb", data=mtcars)
summary(m.glm.cl)
#                Estimate  Std. Error    t value      Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 44.08199770 1.960767641  22.482010 6.225590e-112
# wt          -6.49567966 0.635946018 -10.214200  1.712866e-24
# disp        -0.05635816 0.009436760  -5.972194  2.340843e-09
# wt:disp      0.01170542 0.001965829   5.954445  2.609566e-09

library('lfe')
m.felm <- felm(mpg ~ wt + disp + wt*disp | 0 | 0 | carb, data=mtcars)
summary(m.felm)$coef
#                Estimate Cluster s.e.    t value     Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept) 44.08199770  1.960767641  22.482010 1.846712e-19
# wt          -6.49567966  0.635946018 -10.214200 6.015931e-11
# disp        -0.05635816  0.009436760  -5.972194 1.972266e-06
# wt:disp      0.01170542  0.001965829   5.954445 2.068825e-06
```

The *p*-values differ, though, and I don't know if/how they are used in `interplot` (you could probably figure this out by looking into the method `interplot` is using: `interplot::interplot.default`).

Anyway, `glm.cluster` returns a list where `glm_res` is what we are looking for,

```
names(m.glm.cl)
# [1] "glm_res" "vcov"
```

and what we can feed `interplot` with.

```
library("interplot")
interplot(m=m.glm.cl$glm_res, var1='wt', var2='disp', ci=.9, ralpha=.3, rfill='dodgerblue1') +
  geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed") +
  guides(colour=guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, the `glm.cluster` function does indeed produce the correct model! However, after looking into it further, I don't think the results in `glm_res` are what I'm looking for. In your example, the p-values produced by `summary(m.glm.cl)` come from the model w/ clustered errors but the p-values in `summary(m.glm.cl$glm_res)` appear to be from a regular glm model W/O clustering (the p-values are significantly smaller and match the results produced by just running a simple `glm()` command). Still stuck on this.

Comment: That's not entirely true, simple `glm` yields different _p_-values. You can easily calculate the _p_-values by hand with `2 * pt(-abs(summary(m.glm.cl)[, 3]), df=m.glm.cl$glm_res$df.residual)` which yields exactly those of `felm`. Probably `interplot` uses the covariances to calculate the confidence intervals, you could examine `interplot:::interplot.default` to be exactly sure. You could report the `felm` results and plot with `lm.cluster` then. Anyway, I've [opened an issue at the author's github](https://github.com/alexanderrobitzsch/miceadds/issues/16) for you.